# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 16

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a registration system on my website and I am changing all my mysql statments to PDO statements. When I changed it, I got this error: 
**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 16**

Here is my code...

```
<?php

include("sql.php");
    require("includes/password.php");

session_start(); //Start session for writing

$errmsg = array(); //Array to store errors

    $noterr = array();

$errflag = false; //Error flag

function UniqueID() {
$UID = rand(); //Create unique ID
$check = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UID` = :UID'); //line 16

    $UIDarray = array(
        UID => $UID
);

    $check->execute($UIDarray);
```

sql.php...

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
$dbhost = 'dbhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database connection - `$db` -  is out of scope. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You need to either add it as a function parameter

```
function UniqueID($db) {
                  ^^^
```

and when you call the function

```
UniqueID($db)
```

OR Place the include inside your function

```
function UniqueID() {
    include("sql.php");
```

OR declare the global

```
function UniqueID() {
 global $db
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope in PHP is not global.  Your `$db->execute` call is within the `UniqueID` function, and the function isn't able to access the `$db` variable defined in sql.php.  If you alter your `UniqueId` function to accept a database parameter, and then pass that parameter to the function, you'll be able access it.